# Error handling Swift 2.0 Google Maps Json

Tags: json, google-maps, error-handling, swift2, xcode7

I want to make error handiling for the JSON I receive from google maps,
the thing is I have already wrote it in Swift 1.2 but as I migrate to Swift 2.0 and XCode 7 Beta, the problem rise,
here is the code Swift 1.2:

```
  var error: NSError?

          let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 2.0, do catch is needed...

```
do {
    let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
} catch let error as NSError {
     print(error)
}
```

may be some changes require...but this is the way you have to do in swift 2.0